# RE2 syntax for not matching zero

Tags: google-bigquery, re2

I have following values (strings) in user_id column in bigQuery:

```
g_123_h_34_p_2
g_13_h_14_p_0
g_0_h_14_p_10
```

I want to fetch results on basis of REGEXP_CONTAINS function in query (where clause). BigQuery provides regular expression support using the re2 library.

I want to fetch results where there is no 0 between two '_'. My desired result is:
g_123_h_34_p_2

I am not sure what regular expression i should write in REGEXP_CONTAINS function. I tried following regular expression but it didn't worked for me:

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS (user_dim.user_id, r"^g_[^0][0-9]{1,10}_h_[^0]_p_[^0]$") = TRUE
REGEXP_CONTAINS (user_dim.user_id, r"^g_[1-9]*_h_[^0]*_p_[^0]*$") = TRUE
```

Regex character limitations
Regular expressions with the following special characters aren't supported, as they can cause delays:
* (asterisk)
+ (plus sign)

Answer (score 2):

try either of below

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(str, r'^0_|_0_|_0$')
REGEXP_CONTAINS(str, r'(^|_)0(_|$)')
```

for example

```
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 'g_123_h_34_p_2' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'g_13_h_14_p_0' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'g_0_h_14_p_10' 
)
SELECT * 
FROM t
WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(str, r'(^|_)0(_|$)')
```

will return

```
Row str  
1   g_123_h_34_p_2
```

Comment: Thanks but looks like REGEXP_CONTAINS (user_dim.user_id, r"^g_[^0][0-9]*_h_[^0][0-9]*_p_[^0][0-9]*$") = TRUE works for me. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Why to use more complex regexp if simple one works just fine :o) but it is up to you - you might have something else in mind that is out of scope of this question - so use whatever works for you best